# Kotlin Serialization - Decoding JSON Array from string

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, deserialization, kotlin-multiplatform

Trying to deserialize cached json string to data object and getting exception: `kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject (Kotlin reflection is not available) as the serialized body of kotlinx.serialization.Polymorphic<List>, but had class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonArray (Kotlin reflection is not available)`

Code used to deserialize

```kotlin
internal inline fun <reified R : Any> String.convertToDataClass() =
    Json {
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    }.decodeFromString(R::class.serializer(), this)
```

Code example:

```kotlin
val jsonString  ="""
[{"name1":"value1"}, {"name2":"value2"}]
"""
val dataObject = jsonString.convertToDataClass<List<SomeObject>>()
```

When going through Ktor pipeline everything works fine but it is breaking on attempt to deserialize the same response body cached as string.

I am aware of that `R::class.serializer()` is marked as for internal usage but this is the only way known to me how to deserialize generics from string content.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works but can you not reuse `R` as generic parameter for `decodeFromString`?

Comment: Hi @Dominik. You cannot pass `R` as a parameter if you're using `Json` class function `decodeFromString`. However, your question has led to me to find that `StringFormat` has extension function with same name but different definition, where you can pass `R` as a parameter. Switching to it, solved the error.

Comment: Why not? Do you really get a compiler error for `Json.decodeFromString<R>(this)`?

Comment: Yep, it expects two arguments. This is definition of the function `fun <T> decodeFromString(deserializer: DeserializationStrategy<T>, string: String): T`

Comment: Check https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#introduction-and-references. The sample is `val obj = Json.decodeFromString<Project>(string)` so there should be a fitting overload.

Comment: Correct. As I said, `StringFormat` has an extension function which fits the definition. `StringFormat` is interface which `Json` implements, so extension functions are available for `Json` type of object. Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Ahh okay - sorry I don't know the library that well and didn't quite understand your previous comment. I thought you took an alternative route.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a fitting extension function available at `kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString` that takes one generic parameter, so you could pass `R` as generic to that extension.

Check https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#introduction-and-references. The sample is `val obj = Json.decodeFromString<Project>(string)`, which will fit your needs doing something like this

```
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json    

internal inline fun <reified R : Any> String.convertToDataClass() =
    Json {
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    }.decodeFromString<R>(this)
```

Comment: Please, add import statement to the answer `import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString`. Maybe somebody like me who uses explicit import statements are not aware of extension function.